# Prove that $\oint_{\gamma}^{}{\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz}= -2\pi iInd_{\gamma}(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I have the following statement but I don't see exactly why it's true. So if anyone could help it would be a lot appreciated :

Let $x \in U  $ and $f$ a holomorphic function on $U$\$x$

$f(z) \neq 0 $ ,  $\forall z\in U$\ $x$

$f$ has a pole of order $n\geq 1$

So we have :

$$\oint_{\gamma}^{}{\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz}= -2\pi  niInd_{\gamma}(x)$$

**EDIT :** if $\gamma$ is a loop in $U$\ $x$ we have the statement

I don't see how he jumped to that conclusion ..

Comment: I think that there should be a $n$ somewhere in that equality.

Comment: Does the edit I made changed that ?

Comment: If you have added a $n$ to that equality, I don't see it.

Comment: It's done I've added also the fact that $\gamma$ is a loop

Comment: I would look at the holomorphic $\phi(z):=z^n f(z)$, noting that $\phi'(z)/\phi(z)=n/z+f'(z)/f(z)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a particular case of the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). In general, $\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\mathrm dz$ is the number of zeros of $f$ minus the number of poles (counted with their multiplicities). Since, in this case, there are $0$ zeros and one pole with multiplicith $n$, $\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,\mathrm dz=-n$.